# How to get the overriden culture in a static Webmethod string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm testing the current language of an Aspx page by overriding the current culture in a Base Page (TEST.cs) as follows:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
Page.Culture = "French"
Page.UICulture = "fr";
}
```

I've also created 4 different languages in the App_GlobalResources including French.

Now any aspx page that contains the following code, and has TEST.cs as its base page shows the text in French, despite the browser language settings whether it's French or not.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label" Runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, language %>"></asp:Label>
```

So far so good. Now on one of the aspx pages I'm using a User Control that creates HTML DOM strings with a combination of Ajax and Webmethod in code behind as follows.

```
function language() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/testing.aspx/language",
    data: "{ }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    $("#language").html(data.d);            
}
})

[WebMethod]
public static string language()
{   
StringBuilder language_sb = new StringBuilder();
language_sb.Append(Resources.LocalizedText.language);
return language_sb.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that Resources.LocalizedText.language returns only the language based on the browser language settings and it doesn't recognize the override function of InitializeCulture() in the base page.

How can I solve this problem and use the override language in my static Webmethod?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your InitializeCulture try setting also the Thread Culture like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    Page.Culture = "French"
    Page.UICulture = "fr";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
}
```

Comment: Nope.... It doesn't work. I still get the language set in the browser settings...

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in InitializeCulture, when you call your WebMethod, the application stop or your InitializeCulture is never called?

Comment: I solved the problem by running a function that sets the Thread Culture within each web method.... Is there a better way?

Comment: The problem here is that your WebMethod must be static. If it is an option for you, you can send language header with your ajax call with the headers property in [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
In your WebMethod you must always set the correct culture I guess.